# How to express all the vectors in R3 which are not in the spanning space S

Tags: linear-algebra

[Picture of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eANV.jpg)

Hi,
I think I understand the problem, but I'm not sure on how to properly express the solution.

If I am right, it's asking me for all vectors that are not a linear combination of two given vectors, and therefore not in span S.

In other words its asking me to find all vectors that are linearly independent with two given vectors.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: https://i.ibb.co/9cYGf6B/20181203-121435.jpg  I tried expressing it terms of a vector b, where values are limited to the constraints of the span. Does this seem right?

Comment: In the future, please take the time to enter relevant context for your question—in this case basically the question itself—as text instead of uploading a picture of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen-reading software. (In this case, it was one short sentence, which you really could’ve typed in at least as quickly as it took to take the picture, upload it and link to it.) You can find a quick reference and tutorial for formatting mathematical expressions with MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).